# select tag bug in google chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, select

On google chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m - I'm simply using this code in html:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Option 5 is not highlighted when i hover down to it, but it's clickable. On the other hand is completely ok with firefox or IE. Is it really a chrome bug as they've recently released an update.

Comment: I notice that bug too in the last update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was fixed in 32.0.1700.102 m

Comment: ya. as of 31/1/2014 they've fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

This issue is know and [blogged about on frankcode](http://frankcode.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/chrome-32-broke-the-internet/).

> The following workarounds exist:
>
> - Change windows theme to Windows 7 Basic (may require a certain level of user permission)
> - Use the scroll wheel or up and down arrows (fix for select box only)
> - Upgrade to the Beta release / Canary (I would not recommend this)
> - Move to another browser

(NOTE: It's a known bug which Google must fix. So i recommend: Do not care about it much.)